# Program not reading and printing character

Tags: c, printf, scanf, getchar

This is a program to print a Square of *side = integer* made up of a character.

For eg: Output if character entered is `#`:

[image: Example output]

However it does not read user input and thus also fails to print it in square.

See the code below:

```
    //printing of square of any character problem 5.20
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main( void )
{
     int i, h;
     int side;
     char fillCharacter;

     printf("Enter the side:\n");
     scanf("%d", &side);

     printf("Enter the character with which to make a square of side %d:\n", side );
     scanf("%c", &fillCharacter );

     for( h = 1; h <= side; ++h ) {

       for( i = 1; i <= side; i++ ) {

          printf( "%c ", fillCharacter );
     }
     printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

The program runs as -

[image: Output]

That is, it does not get the character value from the user despite the line for it being present in the source code.

Please help in rectifying the problem.

Comment: Please post the output here, and not in link.

Comment: @Haris: you need a reputation of at least 10 to post images. It is perfectly alright for new users to post links. If the image is useful, a friendly editor may pass by and fix this (and other issues in the post, so thank you Cool Guy!).

Comment: @Jongware oops.. Didn't knew this.. Thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space in the second `scanf()`

```
scanf(" %c", &fillCharacter );
```

This is needed because when you enter the number for the first `scanf()`, the number is read into `side` but the newline character `\n` is left in the input buffer.